# Proving an Inequality using the Triangle Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, proof-verification

Prove that for any nonnegative numbers $a$ and $b$,

$\frac{a+b}{2}\leq\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^3+b^3}{2}}$.

I'm stuck on this proof. It looks like it can be proven by using the triangle inequality, but I have no idea how to begin that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Cube and factor the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Proof without triangle inequality:
$$\frac{a+b}{2}\leq\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^3+b^3}{2}} \iff$$
$$\frac{(a+b)^3}{8} \leq \frac{a^3 + b^3}{2} \iff$$
$$a^2b + ab^2 \leq a^3 + b^3 \iff$$
(Since $a+b\geq0$ as $a,b$ are non-negative)
$$ab \leq a^2 - ab + b^2 \iff$$ 
$$(a-b)^2 \geq 0$$
which is always true.

Answer (score 0):

As for all real numbers the square is always positive:$$(a-b)^2\ge0$$
$$a^2+b^2\ge2ab$$
$$3(a^2+b^2)\ge6ab$$
$$4a^2+4b^2\ge6ab+a^2+b^2$$

$$4a^2+4b^2-4b\ge a^2+b^2+2ab$$

$$a^2+b^2-ab\ge\frac{(a+b)^2}{4}$$

$$ \sqrt[3]{a^2+b^2-ab}\ge\sqrt[3]{{(a+b)^2}/{4}}$$
$$\sqrt[3]{(a^2+b^2-ab)(a+b)/2}\ge\sqrt[3]{{(a+b)^3}/{8}}$$

$$\frac{a+b}{2}\leq\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^3+b^3}{2}}$$ This is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a<b$ and put $\frac{a}{b}=\cos(t)$

we want to prove that

$$(1+\cos(t))^3\leq 4(1+(\cos(t))^3)$$

or

$$\cos(t)(1+\cos(t))\leq 1+(\cos(t))^3$$

which is true since

$\cos(t)\leq 1$ and $$(\cos(t))^2\leq(\cos(t))^3$$